# Bash function scope status when EXIT trap is executed after a program exits with status != 0 (set -e)

Tags: bash, local, readonly, bash-trap

Declaring a local variable in a bash function makes that variable only visible inside the function itself and its children, so if I run:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e

func_one() {
  echo "${var}"
}

func_two() {
  local -r var="var from func_two"
  func_one
}

func_two
```

The output is:

```
var from func_two
```

Even if the *var* variable is declared as local and readonly inside *func_two* can be accessed from the function *func_one*. It is possible, in the latter, to declare a variable with the same name also local and readonly:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e

func_one() {
  local -r var="var from func_one"
  echo "${var}"
}

func_two() {
  local -r var="var from func_two"
  func_one
}

func_two
```

The output is:

```
var from func_one
```

The same happens if *func_one* is called from an EXIT trap:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e

func_one() {                                                                    
  local -r var="var from func_one"                                              
  echo "${var}"                                                                 
}                                                                               

func_two() {                                                                   
  local -r var="var from func_two"                                             
  trap 'func_one' EXIT
  echo "${var}"                                             
}                                                                               

func_two
```

Running the code I receive:

```
var from func_two
var from func_one
```

However, if the EXIT trap is executed after an error (set -e option makes the script exit immediately if a command exits with a non zero status). It looks like it's not possible to reassign the var variable inside *func_one*:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e

func_one() {                                                                    
  local -r var="var from func_one"                                              
  echo "${var}"                                                                 
}                                                                               

func_two() {                                                                   
  local -r var="var from func_two"                                             
  trap 'func_one' EXIT          
  echo "${var}"                                                
  false                                                                         
}                                                                               

func_two
```

Running the code I receive:

```
var from func_two
local: var: readonly variable
```

Can anyone clarify to me why this happens? Thank you in advance.

Comment: I'm tempted to say this is another reason not to use `set -e`, but since `set -e` is defined by POSIX and `local` is a `bash` extension, it's possible that this is a bug in the implementation of `local`. I'll note that if you drop the `-r` option and call `readonly var` after the call to `local`, then the same code works as expected in `dash` (which has its own non-standard implementation of `local`) but produces the same error in `bash`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a bug in Bash.

When you initially install `func_one` as an exit handler, Bash invokes it at the end of the script, after `func_two` has returned. All is well.

When you use a combination of `set -e` and invoke `false` from `func_one`, Bash is exiting the script, and invoking the exit handler, after the call to `false`, in other words, within `func_one`.

Bash implements "exit on error" by invoking `longjmp` to return control to the top level parser, passing the code `ERREXIT`. In the code that handles this case, there is a comment to the effect that the script should forget about any function that was executing, which it does by setting a variable, `variable_context`, to `0`. It looks like `variable_context` is an index into a stack of naming scopes, and setting it back to `0` points it to the top-level global scope.

Next, Bash invokes the trap handler, which invokes `func_one`. Now `variable_context` is `1`, that is, the same value it had within `func_two`. When the script tries to set `var`, Bash looks at the names defined in this context and discovers that `var` is already there, left over from `func_two`.

I confirmed this in the debugger and also with a workaround: if you add an intermediate function call, the script works, because now within `func_one`, `variable_context` is `2` and Bash doesn't see the leftover `var` from `func_two` anymore:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e

func_one() {
  local -r var="var from func_one"
  echo "${var}"
}

func_intermediate() {
  func_one
}

func_two() {
  local -r var="var from func_two"
  echo "${var}"
  trap 'func_intermediate' EXIT
  false
}

func_two
```

Apparently within the Bash code unwinding the function call stack involves actually removing the variables (there is a function called `kill_all_local_variables`); just decrementing `variable_context` (or setting it to `0`) isn't good enough. That's why the script works in the case where `func_two` returns first and is able to clean up its variables before Bash invokes `func_one`.

Update: It looks like `variable_context` is *not* an index into a stack (it's just a function nesting counter), and the code mallocs new space for variables when entering a function? So not 100% sure what's actually going on here, but Bash does find the `func_two` version of `var` inside `func_one`, and adding the intermediate call makes the problem go away, so it's some kind of issue with Bash not cleaning up after `func_two` when leaving it due to the "exit on error" setting and causing `func_one` to inherit its variables.

Comment: Was planning to but it's only been 30 minutes. The bug has existed for at least 12 years so a few more hours probably won't make much of a difference.

Comment: @WillisBlackburn Thank you very much for your answer. If I understand correctly, at the moment the choices are 1) using the workaround or 2) just avoid using set -e.

Comment: I think you could also set a trap handler for ERR and then exit from that handler.